# How to create combine title and menu list in one box (drop down ) in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, dropdown, android-jetpack-compose, menu-list

I have created a drop down menu using jetpack compose. here used card for the menu title. I just  want to combine title box of drop down and body box of drop down using jetpack compose.

Dropdown menu

Answer (score 0):

You can use ExposedDropdownMenu as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72795638/5457853).

```
@Composable
fun ExposedSelectionMenu(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    index: Int,
    title: String? = null,
    textStyle: TextStyle = TextStyle(
        fontWeight = FontWeight.W600,
        fontSize = 14.sp
    ),
    colors: TextFieldColors = ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.textFieldColors(
        containerColor = Color.Transparent,
        focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
        unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
        disabledIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent
    ),
    options: List<String>,
    onSelected: (Int) -> Unit
) {

    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var selectedOptionText = options[index.coerceAtLeast(0)]

    ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
        modifier = modifier,
        expanded = expanded,
        onExpandedChange = {
            expanded = !expanded
        }
    ) {
        TextField(
            modifier = modifier,
            readOnly = true,
            value = selectedOptionText,
            onValueChange = { },
            label = {
                title?.let {
                    Text(it)
                }
            },
            trailingIcon = {
                ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(
                    expanded = expanded
                )
            },
            colors = colors,
            textStyle = textStyle
        )
        ExposedDropdownMenu(
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = {
                expanded = false

            }
        ) {
            options.forEachIndexed { index: Int, selectionOption: String ->
                DropdownMenuItem(
                    onClick = {
                        selectedOptionText = selectionOption
                        expanded = false
                        onSelected(index)
                    },
                    text = {
                        Text(text = selectionOption)
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```